# What command or procedure to use for vscode to display in the terminal, the line of code responsible for displaying a blank page in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

I'm working on a web project with reactjs. For some time, whenever I run my code on vscode, the browser shows me a nice blank page. I don't know why because it didn't happen before and I didn't make any changes to the source code. I read an article  on the web that said it was due to an error that occurred in my code. But despite that, I don't understand because even before this blank page problem, I often had errors in my code and react showed me on the web page instead of the application a black page with the details and the lines errors occurred. But now nothing, just a blank page and in the command line, no errors are reported to me, just warnings.After reading an article on the internet, I realized that I could use error bounds on components to prevent this, but since for some reason
efficiency I couldn't use error limits on all my components, so I had to use it on the element responsible for the crash. But the problem is that I don't know which element is responsible for this and vscode doesn't show me information about the crash. Still, according to the official documentation, vscode should give details of my page crash as well as the location of the error and I'm using a react version greater than 16. I don't know what to do or what resource to use. So I ask for your help. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try checking the browser console ?

Comment: I tried and here are the 3 errors I got:`manifest.json:1 
        
       Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.`, `VM7:328 
        
       edge Translation started`, `bundle.js:1 
        
       Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` . However, I do not have a bundle.js file and my manifest.js file was generated when the react project was created and as I said above, I did not make any modification